Enable Zero-Code Instrumentation for gRPC Endpoint Metrics in a Play Framework App with OpenTelemetry
I have a Scala application built with the Play Framework that exposes a gRPC endpoint. Here's the current setup:

The application is instrumented with opentelemetry-javaagent.
The OpenTelemetry data is sent to New Relic's OTLP endpoint for monitoring.

The problem: While I can see telemetry basic metrics (e.g. process.runtime.jvm.*) in New Relic, there is no data specifically about the usage of the gRPC endpoint (e.g., request counts, response times, errors).
Is it possible to collect and send gRPC endpoint-specific metrics without modifying the application code using OpenTelemetry and view them in New Relic?

You may ask on OpenTelemetry GitHub. HTTP metrics is available but gRPC maybe not. You can also consider contributing if it's confirmed that it's not supported yet.

As @GaëlJ stated, it doesn't seem there is support for zero-code instrumentation. If you look at Supported libraries, support for akka-http, pekko-http, playfraemwrok can be found but it doesn't say anything about play-grpc (I'm assuming you are using this one). It's an open source lib where you can contribute
